# MS SQL Arabic Letters in Latin Collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, arabic, collation

I have store Arabic data in MS SQL database in a field with Latin collation .. I can read it good using old SqlDrv32.dll driver with odbc. Is there any way to convert this data to Arabic collation with correct data?

Comment: You can define the collation at the server, database, or column level.  You should be able to do this.

Comment: yes i can  .. but in this case i don't get the correct letters .. it still be readed  wrong

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is make sure that your column is stored using `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`. The difference is that

- **nvarchar**: stores UTF-16 (i.e. 2 bytes per character) unicode
- **varchar**: stores Ansi (i.e. 1 byte per character) text

Say you wanted to store the text: "مرحبا"

If you were to (correctly) store it into an `nvarchar` column, the table would contain *"مرحبا"*.

## Workaround

But i assume you're not able to change the database to the *correct* column type, that you're stuck with `varchar`, and you just need it to work with a `varchar` column in a Latin-1 collation.

In that case you will need to use your programming language to interpret the bytes of "مرحبا" as Latin-1 directly:

```
| Character | Windows 1256 Hex Code | Windows-1252 |
|-----------|-----------------------|--------------|
| م         | E3                    | ã            |
| ر         | D1                    | Ñ            |
| ح         | CD                    | Í            |
| ب         | C8                    | È            |
| ا         | C7                    | Ç            |
```

So in order to save the:

- in order to save the Windows 1256 text: `مرحبا`
- you must interpret it as: `ãÑÍÈÇ`

And when you save it to the database it will be stored in the `varchar` Latin-1 column as `ãÑÍÈÇ`.

### Then reading it back

Now you also have to load it back. This means you have to take the string:

> ãÑÍÈÇ

which is how it is displayed when you assume it is Windows-1252 encoded, and *assume* it is Windows-1256 encoded.

### But how do i actually convert it?

I don't know the programming language you use, but we can assume a modern kind of language that provides the ability to convert text to encoded byte-sequences.

In the end your goal is to write something like:

```
dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO Users (Name) VALUES (`مرحبا`)");
```

First you have to convert your `string` from "مرحبا" to the Windows-1256 encoded version:

```
String name = "مرحبا";

//Convert the string into a Windows-1256 encoded byte sequence
Encoding arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
byte[] nameAsBytes = arabic.GetBytes(name); //e.g. E3 D1 CD C8 C7

//Convert the byte sequence back to a string, but assume it is Windows-1252
Encoding latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
String latinName = latin1.GetString(nameAsBytes); //e.g. "ãÑÍÈÇ"
```

Now you can write your SQL statement:

```
dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO Users (Name) VALUES ('ãÑÍÈÇ')");
```

Now when you read the value back from the database, it will come at you as a `string`:

```
SELECT Name FROM Users

Name
----------
ãÑÍÈÇ

1 row(s) affected
```

You then have to interpret that text (which is Windows-1252) as Windows-1256:

```
String latinName = reader.GetString("Name"); //"ãÑÍÈÇ"

Encoding latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] nameAsBytes = latin1.GetBytes(latinName);
Encoding arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
String name = arabic.GetString(nameAsBytes);

//name is now مرحب
```

The magic is *assuming* your text is the Windows-1252 encoding. We can convert helper functions to force text to and from Latin1:

```
String ToLatin1(String s)
{
   //"مرحب" ==> "ãÑÍÈÇ"
   //(1256) ==> (1252)

   Encoding from = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
   byte[] hex = from.GetBytes(s);

   Encoding to = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
   String result = to.GetString(hex);

   return result;
}

String FromLatin1(String s)
{
   //"ãÑÍÈÇ" ==> "مرحب"
   //1252    ==> 1256

   Encoding from = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
   byte[] hex = from.GetBytes(s);

   Encoding to = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
   String result = to.GetString(hex);

   return result;
}
```

So it's something like:

```
dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO Users(Name) VALUES (@name)",
      ToLatin1("مرحب")
);
```

and

```
IDataReader rdr = dbConnection.ExecuteReader("SELECT Name FROM Users");
if (rdr.Read())
{
   String name = FromLatin1(rdr.GetString("Name"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for help .. but i still can not fix it .. in ore details  .. i stored arabic data  from vb6 application .. using old odbc driver Sqlsrv32.dll .. in sql server 2000 with collation Latin .. i still can read it in arabic with the same old odbc sql driver .. i have to replace this driver to read my arabic lettters .. now i want to access this data directly without any odbc driver ?? what shall i do ??